# Inialization makes pointer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I'm quite new in C programming and I've tried to read similar questions but I have not been able to solve my particular issue.

I have this small function which returns a pointer to g_Uart0RxBuf array:

```
uint8_t* R_UART0_getBuffer()
{
   uint8_t* pointer_to_buffer;
   pointer_to_buffer = &g_Uart0RxBuf[0];
   return pointer_to_buffer;
}
```

In the calling function I'm doing this:

```
uint8_t* pointer;              //Define pointer variable
pointer = R_UART0_getBuffer(); //Should return a pointer to an uint8_t
```

Honestly I don't understand why I need a cast in order to make this work. Isn't it possible to do it without casting?

Thanks a lot and my apologies for making such a noob question.

Comment: what is the type of `g_Uart0RxBuf`?

Comment: Where exactly do you use  casting?

Comment: typecasting is generally used in the case of interaction/assignment between different datatypes. Hence, to answer your question you need to provide type of "g_Uart0RxBuf"

Comment: There is no initialization in that code, only an assignment.

Comment: Why do you think, you need a cast? Do you get a compiler message that you've hidden from us?

Comment: Show the exact error message

Comment: Questions seeking **debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")** must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No cast is necessary. The issue is down to one of:

1. You are calling `R_UART0_getBuffer` *before* the compiler has seen the declaration of the function, and your now lax C compiler is allowing implicit function definitions (which have been disallowed since C99 but some compilers have it switched on by default!)
2. The compile error actually refers to the statement `pointer_to_buffer = &g_Uart0RxBuf[0];` depending on what the type is in that array.

Comment: This was the issue. Thanks man.